# Set react native component prop through passed reference

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to show/hide a modal based on user interaction (ie - a button press) in a component which is neither a parent or child of the modal itself. I'm currently trying to do so by passing the modal as a prop to the modal controller, but the following errors are thrown depending on which method I call:

- TypeError: modal.setNativeProps is not a function
- TypeError: modal.setState is not a function

Is there a way to show the modal given how this is structured?

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal'

const modalRef = React.createRef();
const modal = <Modal ref={modalRef} isVisible={false}>

<ModalController modal={modalRef} />

export const ModalController = ({modal}) => {

 function onButtonPress(){
   modal.setState({isVisible:true})
   modal.setNativeProps({isVisible:true})
 }

 return (
  <Button title='Show Modal' onPress={onButtonPress()} />
 )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you've gotten a little confused.

Firstly, remember that everything inside `ModalController` is going to execute on every render. Your function `onButtonPress` will be created every render (this is fine), but you are actually **calling** that function when you pass it to `onPress` render . This means you're executing `onButtonPress` on every render, which is probably not what you want.

This is an easy fix - you just remove the `()` so it's just `onPress={onButtonPress}`. Now it'll only trigger when the button is pressed.

More fundamentally, the solution to your problem is much simpler than what you've done in your code. Generally 'refs' are only used in special cases where you really want to tell your components what to do (like telling a ScrollView to scroll to a particular position, or telling an input to focus so the keyboard shows). If you're using a ref it should be very intentional.

So a simple solution to have a component with a button that shows a modal could look like:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Button, Text} from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

export const ModalController = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);

  function onButtonPress() {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title='Show Modal' onPress={onButtonPress} />
      {isModalVisible && <MyModal />}
    </View>
  );
};

const MyModal = () => (
  <Modal>
    <Text>Hey I am a modal</Text>
  </Modal>
);
```

Notice the use of `useState`. This is how you hold 'state' in a functional component like this (as opposed to a class component where you would use `setState`.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have questions!

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, in case there is no parent/child relation between components, the only way I found to pass/set data from one component to another is use a global state manager like [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/). With redux you can easly define a global state and set it from component that fire modal open/close. Modal component reads this state and open/close itself.